# How to find known vulnerability in third party JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, known-vulnerabilities

Currently I am using OWASP Dependency Check to find and mitigate known security issues in third party jars. Is there any similar tool/app to check for known security issue in third party JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

This may seem like a lame answer to you but my rule of thumb is pretty simple and cheaper than trying to validate third party JS libraries

1. Only use well-known, actively maintained, patched libraries like Jquery.  Look at the list of libraries available on Google and that's a great hint you are dealing with reliable code
2. If you are rolling your own, or on the bleeding edge - there is JS Lint. In my experience, almost all security vulnerabilities are due to bugs - see http://www.jslint.com/

Comment: Thanks @danny.. We are only using well-known, actively maintained library... Sometimes well-known library may also have issues which they fix in next version. I want to be updated when third party js library fix some security issue.